# ScrollView going behind button in Android

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

Why is the scrollview going behind the button here?  I want the scrollview to stretch in height depending on the device but cant get it to work as it always goes behind the button.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detail_view"
    style="@style/DetailView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:id="@+id/textview_message_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        </TextView>

         <TextView
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:id="@+id/textview_message_date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        </TextView>

        <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_message_text" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:paddingBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 
             <TextView
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:id="@+id/textview_message_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout style="@style/DetailView.Buttons"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <Button
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_view_file"
            android:text="@string/viewfile"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't leave Bottom Padding, I reckon. Btw, can't you put button in the ScrollView?

Comment: from the posted code I don't see why the `View File` button is where it is. probably something in the style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working copy of what I think you are looking for

1: Moved the buttons to the top of the relative layout ( added an id )
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttons"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

       <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_view_file"
            android:text="Button"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

2: Add in the layout containing the scroll change the width and height to match parent
   but ( CRITICAL ) add android:layout_above="@id/buttons"

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

So putting it all together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/detail_view"
            >


  <!-- Buttons at the top of layout but aligned to the bottom -->
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttons"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_view_file"
            android:text="Button"/>

 </LinearLayout>


 <!-- Linear layout to fill screen, but assigned to layout above the buttons -->
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textview_message_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
     </TextView>

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_message_date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
     </TextView>

     <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_message_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_message_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I removed the styles so I could see it in the layout an make sure this worked before posting. Hope this helps.

Relative layout allows you to layer elements on top of each other. So if that is not what you are looking for you need to make use of the toLeft, toRight, above, below directives to nudge the layouts into the correct position.

Comment: Wow that worked.  I assume this will work on any display.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help, it should work fine. RelativeLayout is a lot more flexible then nesting LinearLayouts. It just takes a little while to get comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you use Relative layout as the root layout. So both layout are placed on the same place but the button layout is declared after the scrollview so it is shown above the scrollview
The opposite would happen if you were defining the button before the scrollview

So you should define it as shown below to achieve what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detail_view"
    style="@style/DetailView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:id="@+id/textview_message_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        </TextView>

         <TextView
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:id="@+id/textview_message_date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        </TextView>

        <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_message_text" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:paddingBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 
             <TextView
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:id="@+id/textview_message_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
         style="@style/DetailView.Buttons"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <Button
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_view_file"
            android:text="@string/viewfile"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or you can try and use LinearLayout as the root view and set

```
layout_height = "0dp" 
layout_weight = "1"
```

to the layout containing the scrollview

using both these way will make the button stick to the bottom of the layout and the top layout will get all the remaining height.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the scrollview going behind the button here?

Because it is coming first in your layout, `ReletiveLayout` and `FrameLayout` can be used to provide Z-ordering, So every child which comes later in your layout having higher z value so it goes up.Add `android:layout_below = "@id/scrollview_message_text"` to your last linearlayout or order your views within in mind of this characteristic of reletivelayout.